# Vertical positioning: I want an element, x, vertically above, y, on desktop, and vertically below, y, on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have text showing first before an image on desktop, that is, to see the full image, the user would require a scroll. but on mobile, i want the image to show first, then the user would scroll to see the text.
How can i achieve this with css.

example html.

```
<body>
<div class="text x"> Some text... </div>
<div class="image y"> <img src="" alt=""/> </div>
</body>
```

Without changing the html, how can i make the .image div appear above the text, vertically. I think this might be possible with absolute positioning, but I'm a little hesitant about using it cos i think it would be too problematic. Height of images are not known.

Please your answers and thoughts will be duly appreciated.

Comment: please post what you have tried..

Comment: I would have used media-queries. Are you familiar with the technique? If you could show some code (your HTML at the very least), i could perhaps write something up for you.

Comment: What the hell is this? `-body-. -div class="text x"- Some text... -/div-. -div class="image y"- -img src="" alt=""- -/div-. -/body-.` Why you don't post the correct html?

Comment: @marcosperezgude edited. just started using stackoverflow. it kept formatting my html like a normal browser would. its correct now. thanks

Comment: @hydrospanners code added now. thank you

Comment: would you accept a javascript solution?

Comment: @aziz yes, but it would be a last resort. I'm not proficient in javascript.

Comment: @AnoopLL i tried float: left, float:right in a container that can only contain one of the divs, so that the one floated right drops below. but it did not work

Comment: try using margin.. if its mobile give minus margin then the image goes up with respect to the margin you are giving..

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1 - Positioning

This approach assumes the height of each `div` is fixed. Basically you move the text div below the image by applying a `top` offset equal to the height of the image div, while the image div is getting a negative `top` offset equal to the height of the text div

```css
/* demo stuff */
body {background:#FFF;text-align: center;}
.image {height:200px;}
.image img {width:100%;height:100%;}
.text {height:100px;background:#000;color:#FFF;}

/* relative positioning method */
div { position: relative; }
.text { top:200px; }
.image { top: -100px; }
```

```html
<div class="text x">Some text...</div>
<div class="image y">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200" alt="">
</div>
```

---

### Method 2 - Flex box

This method requires a wrapper for both divs which has a `flex` display, allowing us to reverse the order by using the `flex-direction: column-reverse` property.

```css
/* demo stuff */
body {background:#FFF;text-align: center;}
.image {height:200px;}
.image img {width:100%;height:100%;}
.text {height:100px;background:#000;color:#FFF;}

/* flex method */
.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="text x">Some text...</div>
  <div class="image y">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Method 3 - jQuery `insertBefore`

You can use jQuery to simply change the order of the div in the DOM using the `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()` commands.

```js
$(".image").insertBefore(".text");
```

```css
/* demo stuff */
body {background:#FFF;text-align: center;}
.image {height:200px;}
.image img {width:100%;height:100%;}
.text {height:100px;background:#000;color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text x">Some text...</div>
<div class="image y">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/960x200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: The image heights is not known. I cant use your first answer, sorry for not mentioning that earlier. Flexbox is perfect but the browser support is not good enough, as i am designing for a theme store that requires wider browser support. Thanks @aziz

Comment: Well then, I have added a jquery solution, let me know if that helps

Comment: i tried the jquery, but it doesn't seem to work. copied the code exactly as you posted it. do i have to add anything in the js file @aziz

Comment: How have you implemented it? You need to load jQuery first and then add a `<script>` tag under it and place the custom code in it. Got a live demo?